# Extracting and using dictionary values (not the keys) in calculations

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

For my first python project I am trying to automate a system I have developed for evaluating the relative strength of sporting teams based on their games.  I see the results of each game as dictionary containing two key and value pairs. I have made some progress as shown below but I am stuck on two issues:

1. Calculating and then using the winning and losing margins
2. Establishing when a game is drawn - as can see below, the system still finds winners and losers even when the game is tied?!

Code so far:

```
some_games = [ {'manchester': 18, 'boston': 3},
 {'cambridge': 17, 'houston': 25}, 
 {'berlin': 10, 'manchester': 10}
 ]

for game in some_games:
    print(game)

for game in some_games:
    for key, value in game.items():
        print(key, "=", value)

for game in some_games:
    winner = max(game)
    print(winner)

for game in some_games:
    loser = min(game)
    print(loser)

for game in some_games:
    for key, value in game.items():
        winner_value = max(game)
        loser_value = min(game)
        winning_margin = winner_value - loser_value
        print(winning_margin)
```

The paragraph immediately above is an example of one of my (very many) attempts to calculate the winning margin. Naturally it doesn't work. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: A good practice here is to publish the error you have : `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` to help you easier.

Comment: Jona I understand.  However what I was showing (perhaps unhelpfully) here was just one of my very many failed attempts.  Each had its own, and often different, error report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that `min(game)` and `max(game)` return a key of the dict. Afterwards, you cannot subtract the keys because they are strings. You have to get the value for each keys, which is what `game[winner_value]` and `game[loser_value]` do.

Here is an excerpt:

```
for game in some_games:
    winner_value = max(game)
    loser_value = min(game)
    winning_margin = game[winner_value] - game[loser_value]
    print(winning_margin)
```

Comment: Darn simple when you know how.  Thanks Jona

Comment: @Roderic The best way to thank me is by upvoting my answer (and accept the answer for the best one) ! ;-)

Comment: Jona, as set out above, I have found that your code: winning_margin = game[winner_value] - game[loser_value]  sometimes produces a negative when it shouldn't

Comment: @Roderic Do you have an example ?

Answer (score 2):

Rewritten your entire code, you could skip the matches that are draw when finding the winners and losers, and you could probably index the match and use find the winning margins easily.

```py
some_games = [ {'manchester': 18, 'boston': 3},
 {'cambridge': 17, 'houston': 25}, 
 {'berlin': 10, 'manchester': 10}
 ]

print("Printing all games")
for game in some_games:
    print(game)

print("\nPrinting game scores")
for game in some_games:
    for key, value in game.items():
        print(key, "=", value)

print("\nPrinting winner")
for i,game in enumerate(some_games):
    if some_games[i][max(game)] == some_games[i][min(game)]:
        print("Draw")
        continue
    winner = max(game)
    print(winner)

print("\nPrinting loser")
for i,game in enumerate(some_games):
    if some_games[i][max(game)] == some_games[i][min(game)]:
        print("Draw")
        continue
    loser = min(game)
    print(loser)

print("\nWinning margins")
for i,game in enumerate(some_games):
    winner_value = max(game)
    loser_value = min(game)
    winning_margin = some_games[i][winner_value] - some_games[i][loser_value]
    print(winning_margin)
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapid and accurate (I have tested the code) response Suraj.  A question: what is "i"?  I see its some sort of arbitrary variable - I replaced it with "j"and it still worked.  Could it represent each key/value pair?

Comment: You should have noted that I used the `enumerate` function, which basically adds a counter to an iterable, so your able to use the index in your code. Supposing you have a list [10,11,12], instead of iterating using just a for loop which would return `10,11,12`, using an enumerator would return it along with the index `(0,10), (1,11), (2,12)`. You can look into the documentation https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html

Comment: Suraj, I have found Jona's suggestion has helped me forward.  At my level of understanding your solution, which might have longer-term advantages, seems unnecessarily complicated